# How to check whether it .mdb file format dragged in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I try the next way:

```
this.AllowDrop = true;
this.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(Form_DragEnter);

void Form_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     // here I need to check whether it access .mdb format
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
     {
         e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
     }
     else
     {
         e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
     }
 }
```

How to chech it ? In `DataFormats.` there is no database format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] FileList;

if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
{
    FileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
}
else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
{
    FileList = new string[] {e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, false).ToString()};
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

Then loop through the string array [checking file extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)